# sbt build file dependency syntax(or pattern)

Tags: scala, build, sbt

i just started to learn scala and the build tool I use is sbt. Here I have to write dependencies for each sample project. I copied some dependencies from internet and pasted, but I don't get the syntax(or pattern) how to write a dependency by my own.
Can someone please tell me how the keywords are arranged and what is the pattern of writing a dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quote from the Josh Suereth [book](http://www.manning.com/suereth2/)

> Defining Dependencies sbt provides a convenient syntax for defining Maven/Ivy dependencies using the % method. To define a ModuleID in sbt, just write “groupId” % “artifactId” % “version” and it will automatically become an instance of a ModuleID.

Consider this dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "iv.alex" % "commons" % "100500"
```

In this line we have three parts:

```
libraryDependencies              - setting key
+=                               - operator
"iv.alex" % "commons" % "100500" - initialization part
```

This initialization part constructs a `ModuleID`, which is required by `libraryDependencies` setting key. It consists from other three parts from the quote:

```
"iv.alex" - groupId
"commons" - artifactId
"100500"  - version
```

But `libraryDependencies` key is actually a `Seq[ModuleID]`, so you have the second operator `++=` which expects a sequence of moduleIds:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("group" % "artifact" % "version", etc...)
```

The most common way is to store dependencies in stores like [maven cetnral](http://search.maven.org/). So if you want to add you own dependency, for example you want to find `Akka` 2.2.3 for scala 2.11, first find it ([link](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C411317036)), then you need to find `.pom` file or some cases it would be written like [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.10/2.3-M1), so you need the foloowing lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

It is easy to translate into sbt dependency, like i've described above:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3-M1"
```

**Note!** that i've written `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor"` two percentage symbols, it means that i need a library with the same version of scala which i have in my `scalaVersion` setting key. If you notice in maven style dependency, artifact id contains scala version: `akka-actor_2.10`, but not in out sbt dependency. If you **don't** have scala version in you artifactId, then you `shouldn't` write it as `%%` leave just **one** `%`